# How to add Dexie addons to TypeScript db file?

Tags: dexie

Hi does anyone know how to add addons to a TS Dexie db?
This is what they show in the docs but they don't show how to do it in TS.

```js
const db = new Dexie('MySyncedDB', {addons: [dexieCloud]});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor that derives from Dexie, pass the addons in your call to super()

```
class MyDexie extends Dexie {
  ...
  constructor() {
    super('myDbName', { addons: [dexieCloud] });
    ...
  }
}
```